# How to store file path and type with timestamp in database?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I would like to store uploaded files (like photo, video, PDF, Excel....) in a database. When I upload a file, the data that should be stored are file path, type and timestamp. My database columns are id,file,type,timestamp.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: (1) What exactly is your question? Data types? Handling files? Unique identifiers? File or MIME types? Date-times and current moment? JDBC? SQL? (2) Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. Which ever issue is your question, I would bet it has been asked and answered amongst these several million questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static String FILE_PATH = "home\user\Report\"; //File will be created in this folder
private static String FILE_EXTENSION = ".pdf";   //this will be extension of file
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss"); // add S if you need milliseconds
String filename = FILE_PATH + df.format(new Date()) + "." + FILE_EXTENSION;
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).  `Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS).toString().replace("-","").replace(":","")` → 20170618T203834Z  (standard ISO 8601 “basic” format)

Answer (score 0):

I think you ask how to insert information into your MySQL databse with vanilla java (no [hibernate](http://hibernate.org)).

Vanilla Java Example ([alvinalexander.com](https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-insert-example-preparedstatement)):

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * A Java MySQL PreparedStatement INSERT example.
 * Demonstrates the use of a SQL INSERT statement against a
 * MySQL database, called from a Java program, using a
 * Java PreparedStatement.
 * 
 * Created by Alvin Alexander, http://alvinalexander.com
 */
public class JavaMysqlPreparedStatementInsertExample
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    insertDataBase("uploads/demo","pdf");
  }


  public static insertDataBase(String filePath,String extension) {

   try
    {
      // create a mysql database connection
      String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
      Class.forName(myDriver);
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "");

      // create a sql date object so we can use it in our INSERT statement
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      java.sql.Date timeStamp = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());

      // the mysql insert statement
      String query = " insert into upload (file, type, timestamp)"
        + " values (?, ?, ?)";

      // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
      PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
      preparedStmt.setString (1, filePath);
      preparedStmt.setString (2, extension);
      preparedStmt.setDate   (3, timeStamp);

      // execute the preparedstatement
      preparedStmt.execute();

      conn.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.err.println("Got an exception!");
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }


  }
}
```

Before you can run the code you need to add the mysql driver to your classpath with maven or [download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html) it.
Hope it helps you!